# Docker behind squid proxy

Tags: docker, squid, docker-registry

Im running a squid http proxy with squidguard and already configured a dest block on squidguard with the domainlist of the allowed domains, also configured the docker.service.d to have a http proxy (image below) but is getting me an weird error.

Domain whitelisted:
docker.io and registry-1.docker.io

Http proxy: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmyO5.png)

Error: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Btvq0.png)

Access log: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWJfD.png)

Thanks :)

Comment: What's with all the images? Anything important should be pasted as text whenever possible, and images avoided. Some people cannot see images.

Comment: Sorry about that didn't know, it was just a matter of visualization, gonna change.